# PWA. Service worker notifications appearing multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I have website with service worker running. I can print notifications it works quite well but I need to show notifications only once. But now same message appearing every time when I refresh a page. Is it possible to show notifications only once? 
There is my code:

```
function displayNotification() {
  if (Notification.permission == 'granted') {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(reg) {
      var options = {
        body: 'Welcome!',
        icon: '/css/logo.png',
        vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
        data: {
          dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
          primaryKey: 1
        }
      };
      reg.showNotification('My name', options);
    });
  }
}


navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
  if (result === 'granted') {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
      displayNotification();
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to show notifications from within the context of a service worker's execution. You'd normally do that when a service worker is "woken up" via a [`push` event](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/handling-messages).

It's also possible to show notifications from within the context of a web page. Doing that does not require a service worker at all. You can use the same notifications and permissions API without involving a service worker at all, if your use case is showing a single notification immediately after a user grants notification permissions.

Here's a sample illustrating how you could do that. It cheats a little bit because instead of checkin for the first visit, it will only show the notification when there's a change in the notification permissions to `'granted'`. Since this will normally only happen once as opposed to every visit, it should accomplish the same thing.

```js
if ('Notification' in window && 'permissions' in navigator) {
  function showNotification() {
    const title = 'The title';
    const options = {
      body: 'The body.',
    };
    new Notification(title, options);
  }

  navigator.permissions.query({name: 'notifications'}).then(status => {
    if (status.state === 'prompt') {
      status.onchange = () => {
        if (status.state === 'granted') {
          showNotification();
        }
      };

      document.querySelector('#notification')
        .addEventListener('click', () => Notification.requestPermission());
    }
  });  
}
```

```html
<button id="notification">Enable Notification</button>
```